# Existence of $dom R$ and $ran R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Intro. to Set Theory problem 2.1 we have -

Let $R$ be a binary relation; let $A = \cup(\cup R)$. Prove that $(x, y) \in R $ implies that $x \in A$ and $y \in A$.

Why do we have the double union, wont a single union mean the same thing.

My solution to the problem is -

$ (a, b) = \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\} \} \in R$
this implies that $ \{a , b\} \in R$ this implies that $a \in R$ and $b \in R$ and since $ R \subset A$ this implies that $ a \in A$ and $b \in A $.

Is this correct.

Thanks

Comment: How does $\{a,b\}\in R $ follow ? Same thing, how do $a\in R, b\in R$ follow ? This is why you need the double union

Comment: Who's the author of Introduction to Set Theory?

Comment: From Jech and Hrbacek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see with an example: $R=\{(0,1),(1,2)\}$. Explicitly,
$$
R=\bigl\{\{\{0\},\{0,1\}\},\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}\bigr\}
$$
Then
$$
\bigcup R=\bigr\{\{0\},\{0,1\},\{1\},\{1,2\}\bigr\}
$$
and finally
$$
\bigcup\bigcup R=\{0,1,2\}
$$
Therefore, no: one union doesn't suffice.

In general, if $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\in R$, then
$$
\{a\}\in\bigcup R,\qquad \{a,b\}\in\bigcup R
$$
so
$$
a\in\bigcup\bigcup R,\qquad b\in\bigcup\bigcup R
$$